# problem runnig a python code via ubuntu bash shell in windows 10

Tags: python, bash, numpy, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a code in python which uses numpy and when I try to run it on ubuntu bash shell in windows 10 there is an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
 File "kepler.py", line 2, in <module>   
  import numpy as np  
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

while numpy has already been installed in my windows and when I try the same code via windows command prompt it works well. I have tried to install numpy via ubuntu bash shell with this command

```
pip install numpy --user
```

The installation finishes successfully but when running the code "kepler.py" that error message shows up again. Then I type again

```
pip install numpy --user
```

but I get this message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.16.3)
```

Comment: What version of Python are you starting on the bash session? Bash should have both Python 2.7 and Python3.x installed. it might be that you're starting one of them that doesn't have numpy installed.

Comment: Can you install the package without using the --user flag since the --user flag  tells Pip to install packages in some specific directories within your home directory and the package may not be available in the scope of bash shell. Just mentioning a possibility

Comment: @Manumathew Maybe I should add the package to the path, but I don't know how.

Comment: @Manumathew now when I type `pip install numpy --user` I get this message: `Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.16.3)`

Comment: @HampusLarsson now I'm using python 3.5.2, but first python 2.7 was the default one but I changed the default to python 3.

Comment: @ndee Your comment above shows that you've installed numpy on python 3.6, but you use python 3.5 to run the script. Try using `pip3.5 install numpy` to install numpy on python 3.5

Comment: @AliTou I did it and this is the error: `Installing collected packages: numpy
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy'
Consider using the "--user" option or check the permissions.`

Comment: Sounds like your user doesn't user doesn't have permission to install it globally. Either use the `--user` flag, or try to `sudo`the install.

Comment: @HampusLarsson I tried with `--user` and I received this warning: `WARNING: The scripts f2py, f2py3 and f2py3.5 are installed in '/home/nazanin/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.`
`Successfully installed numpy-1.16.3`

Comment: It says it successfully installed numpy. Is your problem solved now?

Comment: @AliTou Yes, solved using `pip3.5 install numpy --user` . Thank you